# Save positive and negative samples used in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow

I use Tensorflow Object Detection API with MobilenetV2 as network backbone and SSD as meta-structure to do the object detection job.

In SSD, for each anchor point, we make several candidate bounding boxes with different aspect_ratios. For each bounding box, if its intersection with the bounding box ground-truth is greater than a threshold, we say that this bounding box is positive. Otherwise, it is negative. And then we use these positive and negative to do the training. (So it is important to note that it is NOT the entire image is used to train, but only one (or several) crops of these images are used)

To debug, I'd like to save these positive and negative crops to hard disk to see what are really samples that the algorithm uses to train.

I read the python code of Tensorflow Object Detection API but I'm lost :(

If you have any hint, please show me !

Thanks !